# Meromorphic Functions that satisfy a first order algebraic differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions, meromorphic-functions

I have been writing a project on elliptic functions and in this project I prove the following theorem:
Suppose a meromorphic function $f$ satisfies an algebraic addition theorem, that is there exists a polynomial $F$ such that
$$F(f(z_1),f(z_2),f(z_1+z_2))=0$$
for all $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$. Then $f$ is either elliptic, singly periodic or rational. I also heard that if $f$ satisfies 
$$P(f(z),f'(z))=0 $$ for some polynomial $P$ then $f$ also belongs to the three classes given. My question is, is the second theorem true, and if so does anyone know a resource containing a proof I can reference?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of uniformization theorem. An algebraic curve (a Riemann surface) is uniformized by the plane or the sphere if it has euler characteristic $\geq 0,$ which means that the Riemann surface is a sphere (corresponding to a rational function), a cylinder (periodic function) or a torus (elliptic function).

Comment: Thanks for that! That sounds like it will be beyond the scope of my project, but do you know of a book that contains the proof that I can reference?

Answer (score 0):

N. I. Akhiezer proves a more general statement in [his book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=1P20oORtnRwC&pg=PA44):

> Any two elliptic functions with the same periods are connected by an algebraic relation.

His proof relies on representing an arbitrary elliptic function as $R_1(\wp)+R_2(\wp)\wp^\prime$, where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are rational functions, and noting that one can always algebraically eliminate $\wp$ and $\wp^\prime$ through their relation ${\wp^\prime}^2=4\wp^3-g_2\wp-g_3$. From here, the case of relating an elliptic function and its derivative algebraically becomes a special case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually proved the first statement in my original post using material from Akheizer. What I'm looking for is the converse to the theorem you gave: that if a meromorphic function is related to it's derivative algebraically, then it is either elliptic, singly periodic or rational.